# Date is null rather than using default value

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to write a simple script that prompts a user for a value, and if the user chooses to not insert anything, will use the default values I have specified. The way it is functioning, if a user inserts nothing, the value is null. I feel like this should be simple but I have not been able to find an answer using google.

```
DECLARE 
jobfromdate date default SYSDATE - 1;
jobtodate date default SYSDATE;
BEGIN
  jobfromdate := &jobfromdate;
  jobtodate := &jobtodate;
   dbms_output.put_line(TO_CHAR(jobfromdate, 'MM-DD-YYYY'));
   dbms_output.put_line(TO_CHAR(jobtodate, 'MM-DD-YYYY'));
END;
```

Comment: Your code always sets the variables to the default value, but then after that it always reassigns them a new value, based on the substitution variables (&). So the defaults are effectively ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated here you can't prompt from PL/SQL, only pass paramaters https://community.oracle.com/thread/397514?tstart=0

To use default value rather than null you can use COALESCE or NVL

```
SELECT COALESCE( jobfromdate, l_default_date) result
FROM jobdates;
```